# Comparing the entire response body by storing in one file and compare that file with current response in postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-newman

I am doing automation script for Functional testing my query is

1. Send the request and store the entire response body in one file.
2. Again they send the request and get the new response.
3. Compare the new response body with a stored response file.
4. Previous response and new response should be equal

I have tried below solution

[image]

```
var serverData = json.parse (responseBody); 

var JSONtoCompare ={};

tests ["Body is correct"] = serverData === JSONtoCompare;
```

I am getting an error below:

> Body is correct | AssertionError: expected false to be truthy.

so please help me to overcome this issue. I want to store the entire response in one file and compare it with a new response in the postman.

Answer (score 1):

In the Postman, using variable to compare JSON object more easy and fast instead of file save.

Also only manual saving possible by selecting `Save Response` in output Body section
[image]

Two APIs call possible for your test scenario.

1. First API Call will save into `first_response` variable
2. Second API Call will compare between `first_response` variable and `it's response`.

***Both** API is save REST endpoint with save parameter

### 1. First API call, save it in `Tests` tab

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set('first_response', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

[image]

### 2. Second API call, compare it in `Tests` tab

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const firstResponse = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('first_response'));

pm.test('Response is idential to other response', function() {
    const isEqual = _.isEqual(firstResponse, jsonData);
    pm.expect(isEqual).to.be.true;
})
```

The `_.isEqual()` function: is used to find that whether the 2 given arrays(or object) are same or not.

[image]

So you can compare two JSON postman responses using this method.

### 3. Auto testing.

Also you can test automatically by `Run Collection` or [`newman`](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/)

Select  `Run Collection`

[image]

Start `Run Collection`

[image]

Run Result

[image]

Newman test result

#1 Export collection

[image]

#2 run it by `newman` - it should be install by `npm install -g newman`

```
newman run <collection name>
```

[image]

Comment: @SunandaMenashinkai, you are welcome, don't forget vote me by pressing up arrow in my answer. It will support keep answer.

Comment: This is a great answer. Should be upvoted more.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the solution for this senario..

1 write the code in test tab of request, store the response with variable of csv file ganesh is variable name in csv file.
2 call the file in collection run
3 write the below code in test tab of the request.

```
const response1=pm.iterationData.get("ganesh"); //console.log(response1); 
pm.test("The existing response and server response are equal", function () 
{ const jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.expect(jsonData).to.eql(response1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked postman team to add this feature in the standard solution ([see request](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/12065)).

We had similar needs : testing a lots of api response body for non-regression testing.
The whole test suite is arround 8000 files with various volume (431 Ko == 10_000 line to 1Ko == a few lines). The big files are a difficult to test when using our beloved pm.test lib :

```
pm.response.to.have.body("response_body_string");// is not clear where there is a regression among those 10_000 lines.
pm.expect(jsonData.value).to.eql(100); //is too long if we need to test a 10_000 field json
```

Right now, the best work around we found is the following one :

1. The template storage is located into a web service where we can copy past files (template) into the correct forlder. Those template can be acces using an id.
   The web service keep also the comparison logic (Json patch using external lib installed using npm).
2. The end point is a POST with the id (the template) + the body (the current response) and return 200 if no regression, error otherwise a json patch file with explicit path of the error

[image: Sequence diagram]

Tips : we like using json patch lib for check regression, based on RFC 6902. see explaination bellow of the patch : it takes two json and return what change occure (add, remove, replace, ...) the path and the value.

```
var  template = { a :100, b:200 }
var response = { a: 101}
var patch = jsonPatch.patch(template,reponse)
pm.expect(patch.length).to.eql(0);
                            |
                          ERROR : [
                                      {
                                          "op": "remove",
                                          "path": "/b"
                                      },
                                      {
                                          "op": "replace",
                                          "path": "/a",
                                          "value": 101
                                      }
                                  ]
```